# Foreign key failure when inserting into child table ( referencing composite unique index)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have problem when trying to insert row into my child database table.

Here is my parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE `payables` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `currency_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `payables_id_type_unique` (`id`,`type`),
  KEY `payables_currency_id_foreign` (`currency_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `payables_currency_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`currency_id`) REFERENCES `currencies` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And here is my child table:

```
CREATE TABLE `pays` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transaction_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `payable_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `payable_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pays_transaction_id_unique` (`transaction_id`),
  KEY `pays_user_id_index` (`user_id`),
  KEY `pays_status_id_index` (`status_id`),
  KEY `pays_payable_id_index` (`payable_id`),
  KEY `pays_payable_type_index` (`payable_type`),
  KEY `pays_payable_id_payable_type_foreign` (`payable_id`,`payable_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `pays_payable_id_payable_type_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`payable_id`, `payable_type`) REFERENCES `payables` (`id`, `type`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `pays_status_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `statuses` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `pays_transaction_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`transaction_id`) REFERENCES `transactions` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `pays_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

That is the table I'm trying to seed, the parent table is already seeded.

I'm using laravel query builder to create these tables, so if anyone more experienced with databases could review the code, that would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry just missed that i was inserting different data type to my column.